# Defaulting Picklist Value using a URL Hack (Spring '20 version)

Tags: urlhacking, spring-20

Im trying to use the new URL Hack available in the Spring '20 release in LEX and running into an issue with getting a picklist value to default when the user clicks a custom button. The custom button will clone the existing record and then prepopulate one custom field. Any thoughts/suggestions are appreciated. Thanks ahead of time.

`/{!Case.Id}/e?clone=1&defaultFieldValues=Pick_List_Field__c={!URLENCODE("Prepopulate This Value")}`

Spring '20 Release Notes on the Topic

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_general_lex_navigate_to_record_dfv.htm

Comment: So I think Ive figured out the issue and an alternative solution. Im going to change the url to create a NEW record but prepopulate all the fields that we need to clone. If anyone has another way please share. But from reading this blog it sounds like URL Hacking is not available for the Edit/Clone pages.  http://theblogreaders.com/url-hacking-back-salesforce-lightning-experience-spring-20-release/

Comment: For prepopulating fields for edits a custom action or flow is a possible approach